# Game Maker Studio - Preventing objects from sliding vertically

Tags: collision, game-maker

When my object jumps over a block, if it cannot, it sticks with the side of the wall for a few seconds before the object drops slightly and sticks again until it hits the floor. During this time, the user can jump again allowing them to bypass any wall.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,Room))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,Room))
    {
        x += sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
}
x += hsp;
//VerticalCollision
if (place_meeting(x,y+vsp,Room))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x,y+sign(vsp),Room))
    {
        y += sign(vsp);
    }
    vsp = 0;
```

The above code handles collisions in the game, with experimenting I've messed it up even more now. The character will stand against a wall and everything will freeze...
I'm using a collision mask but that hasn't helped.

Comment: could you show how the current logic is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if we could see your jumping/movement code.
Generally, Freezing is caused by infinite while loops, try adding a limiter.

```
if (place_meeting(x+hsp,y,Room))
{
    var a = 64;
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hsp),y,Room) and 64 > 0 )
    {
        a --;
        x += sign(hsp);
    }
    hsp = 0;
}
```

Also, why are you colliding with Room? Whats Room?